# ! in new HTML file is not working in VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

When I create an HTML file in VS Code and type `!`, it automatically types the default template for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

However, I don't know why but it does not work right now. I can still type `html:5` in the new HTML file to auto-fill the template; although I find myself simply typing `!` is easier, I want to recover the feature. How can I do it?

Comment: have a look in the emmet extension if they still have the `!` macro defined, if not you can define a user custom macro, it not only worked in a new HTML, it worked in any HTML, I have written my own HTML start template snippet, that will always work (unless they drop snippet functionality).

Answer (score 1):

It caused by the VSCode update 1.69...I think Microsoft will restore the "bug"(someone may thought it isn't a bug)

I met this problem yesterday, it needs to set `emmet.TriggerExpansionOnTab` and `emmet.UseInlineCompletions` to true

but it can't perform like before, after press `!`, you need press `Tab` to autocomplete it

I get this from VSCode github issue page: [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154375#issuecomment-1179730279)